# Distribution of theological positions of evangelical churches in the 21st century

Tags: reference-request, evangelicalism, demographics

I am looking for some statistics of how many evangelical churches are Reformed, Lutheran, Anglican, Methodist, Pentecostal, etc.

- Historical data would be great, but I'm more interested in current numbers.
- World-wide scope is fine, but preferably North America, or better yet, by country.
- Statistics can be by number of churches or number of members.  Both would be great.

Comment: This gives numbers of members for each denomiation. Is that what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Christian_denominations_by_number_of_members

Comment: @DJClayworth Well, the raw data maybe there, but then I'll have to determine for each church under each denomination who is evangelical and who is not.  Example: under Lutheranism, ELCA (Evangelical Lutheran Church of America) is not evangelical, but EFCA (Evangelical Free Church of America) is, although both have "evangelical" in the name (see [my other answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/85783/10672)).  So I hope someone else may have done the work.  But thanks for the reference.

Comment: To take one example, working out which Anglican congregations are evangelical and which are not is going to be very hard. Most would have a mix of people who self-identify as evangelical and those who don't.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm aware that a single congregation may have some evangelical members.  So for this question, the statistics can count only whole churches or whole congregations that self identify as evangelical.  Just noticed yesterday that in Australia, several Anglican dioceses self-identify as evangelical and some non-evangelical dioceses have evangelical bishop !  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_Anglicanism#Anglican_Church_of_Australia)

Comment: You might also read: https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2019/09/the-end-of-evangelical/598423/

Comment: @DJClayworth Wow, Prof. Alan Jacobs was quite pessimistic on evangelicals as a whole to "steal back" their historic identity.  My sense is as long as evangelical church pastors and teachers are still clear on what the label means, and as long as their members can survive the temptation to politicize the label, it still has a strong theological identity to survive.  At least measuring from recent scholarly publications, I can still see a well-defined **center**, even in their serious engagement with Catholicism too (I can cite a few serious books published in past 5 years).